# What is the generator of normal law $N(0,1)$ using below inequality?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

My friend sent me the following Exercice for solving  :

**Exercice**:
Write the generator of normal law $N(0,1)$ using the following inequality :

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}: \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)\leq \sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi}{e}}\dfrac{1}{\pi}\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\tag{1}$

**Attempt:** I have tried to find moment generatrice function by assumption that I have a continious probability density function  such that I tried to evaluate $M_X(t) =\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(tx) f(x) dx $  with $f(x)=\exp(-x^2/2)$ then i multiplied both side of inequality
$(1)$ by  $\exp(tx) $ the inequality become :
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(tx)\exp(-x^2/2)\leq \sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi}{e}}\dfrac{1}{\pi}\dfrac{\exp(tx)}{x^2+1}\tag{2}$, integrate both side over $(-\infty,\infty)$ then assume I have got closed form of RHS and LHS of inequality $(2)$ after integration , Does this mean that I have got something relate to  generator  of Normal law $N(0,1)$ ? and if no then how I can get that generator using inequality $(1)$?

Comment: I was hoping to clarify a few things in this question. First off, what exactly is a "generator" in this context? In your attempt, you write the moment generating function $M_X(t)$ (MGF), however, you seem to be integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, whereas the actual MGF would only integrate along $x<0$ (unless you meant characteristic function, in which case you need $\exp(itx)$). Next, it's not at all clear what the goal of this question is. Are you trying to find an upper bound on the MGF? What's the ultimate goal of this exercise?

Comment: I said in my question I didn't understand the goal of this question but I think  to get upper bound of MGF

Comment: It does still seem a bit strange, especially because the MGF for the normal is not hard to compute by completing the square, whereas the upper bound is proportional to a Cauchy distribution, whose MGF would require basic complex analysis to compute. See the MGF here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: Since we have the inequality we should use **acceptance rejection** method to simulate the normale low (find the generator)